# How to set variables in a new PowerShell object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script to update Azure AD Privileged Identity Management which requires an object in the format below.

I want to be able to pass variables to the object, e.g. '{"required":$MFA}', where $MFA comes from a variable. I've tried the script block below but it doesn't recognize $MFA as a variable. Any ideas?

```bsh
# Set MFA Variable
$MFA = "True"

# Create object
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    RuleIdentifer     = "JustificationRule"
    Setting = '{"required":$MFA}'
}

#Output object
write-host $myObject
```

The output just writes the $MFA text. It doesn't substitute $MFA for "True"

```
@{RuleIdentifer=JustificationRule; Setting={"required":$MFA}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify strings using [both single quotes and double quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=span%20multiple%20lines.-,All%20the%20lines%20in%20a%20here%2Dstring%20are%20interpreted%20as,not%20replaced%20by%20their%20values.) in Powershell.

The difference is obviously which characters inside have to be escaped, but also that single-quote strings doesn't do variable substitution, only double-quote strings do.

So a quick rewrite of your code outputs what you want:

```
# Set MFA Variable
$MFA = "True"

# Create object
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    RuleIdentifer     = "JustificationRule"
    Setting = "{""required"":$MFA}"
}

#Output object
write-host $myObject
```

Outputs:

```
@{RuleIdentifer=JustificationRule; Setting={"required":True}}
```